# How to pull in Google Contact List into Meteor App

Tags: javascript, meteor, google-contacts-api

Im trying to make a dropdown list of the signed in users Google contacts in my Meteor app, but can't seem to get the Google permissions to work right.  I have Google Authentication working just fine, using accounts-base and accounts-google, and came across [selectize-google-contacts](https://atmospherejs.com/rcy/selectize-google-contacts) package which uses the [percolate:google-api](https://atmospherejs.com/percolate/google-api) to interact with Google's API, but keep getting the following error:

```
Exception in Google Api callAndRefresh: Error: Auth token not found.Connect your google account [403]
at Object.GoogleApi._call (http://localhost:3000/packages/percolate_google-api.js?f5ed85b086e156f073ebc853af885cee23fdedc3:132:16)
at Object.GoogleApi._callAndRefresh (http://localhost:3000/packages/percolate_google-api.js?f5ed85b086e156f073ebc853af885cee23fdedc3:92:10)
at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/packages/percolate_google-api.js?f5ed85b086e156f073ebc853af885cee23fdedc3:155:17)
at Object.wrapAsync [as get] (http://localhost:3000/packages/percolate_google-api.js?f5ed85b086e156f073ebc853af885cee23fdedc3:53:17)
at Template.selectizeGoogleContacts.onRendered.$.selectize.load (http://localhost:3000/packages/rcy_selectize-google-contacts.js?3223a2bd0dd55e2f7ec72836f52e1172349b8426:105:17)
at null.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/packages/jeremy_selectize.js?c546a4e24dda2fb546e0e81461e3b48f81e80f0e:1608:8)
at $.extend.load (http://localhost:3000/packages/jeremy_selectize.js?c546a4e24dda2fb546e0e81461e3b48f81e80f0e:1743:7)
at $.extend.onSearchChange (http://localhost:3000/packages/jeremy_selectize.js?c546a4e24dda2fb546e0e81461e3b48f81e80f0e:1607:9)
at http://localhost:3000/packages/jeremy_selectize.js?c546a4e24dda2fb546e0e81461e3b48f81e80f0e:877:8
```

My server.js file looks like this:

```js
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup

    // Google Login
    ServiceConfiguration.configurations.remove({
      service: "google"
    });
    ServiceConfiguration.configurations.insert({
      service: "google",
      requestPermissions:'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly',
      clientId: "00000000000",
      loginStyle: "popup",
      secret: "00000000000"
    });


  });
```

Im guessing that the `requestPermissions:'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly',` isn't the way to request permission to access contacts - any thoughts?

Comment: maybe, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22735826/meteor-access-google-contacts-of-loggedin-user/22749934#22749934

Comment: I was able to get my app to at least request the appropriate permissions during the login process, but I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to request an offline token for this to work.  The example app (which I have since added to the github repo for this package) has this client side setup:

```
Accounts.ui.config({
  requestPermissions: {
    google: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly', 'email']
  },
  requestOfflineToken: {
    google: true
  }
});
```

Comment: Accounts.ui.config works in client only not on server!